# How to Convert Array-like String to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a string that looks like an array: `"[918,919]"`. I would like to convert it to an array, is there an easier way to do this than to split and check if it is a number? Thanks

Comment: I guess no easier way without split and check.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse`.

```
var myArray = JSON.parse("[918,919]");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the brackets at the beginning and the end, then use:

```
str.split(",")
```

which will return an array split by the comma character.

**EDIT**

```
var temp = new Array();
temp = "[918,919]".slice( 1, -1).split(",");
for (a in temp ) {
temp[a] = parseInt(temp[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JSON.parse` the string must have " and not ' otherwise the code will fail.

for example:

```
let my_safe_string = "['foo','bar',123]";
let myArray = JSON.parse(my_safe_string)
```

the code will fail with

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

instead if you use " all will work

```
let my_safe_string = "["foo","bar",123]";
let myArray = JSON.parse(my_safe_string);
```

so you have two possibility to cast string array like to array:

- Replace ' with " `my_safe_string.replace("'",'"');` and after do `JSON.parse`
- If you are extremely sure that your string contain only string array you can use eval:

example:

```
let myArray = eval(my_safe_string );
```